# SSRS query and WHERE with multiple

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

Being new with SQL and SSRS and can do many things already, but I think I must be missing some basics and therefore bang my head on the wall all the time.

A **report** that is almost working, **needs to have more results** in it, based on conditions.

My working query so far is like this:

```
SELECT projects.project_number, project_phases.project_phase_id, project_phases.project_phase_number, project_phases.project_phase_header, project_phase_expensegroups.projectphase_expense_total, invoicerows.invoicerow_total
FROM   projects INNER JOIN 
                project_phases ON projects.project_id = project_phases.project_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                project_phase_expensegroups ON project_phases.project_phase_id = project_phase_expensegroups.project_phase_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                invoicerows ON project_phases.project_phase_id = invoicerows.project_phase_id
WHERE  ( projects.project_number = @iProjectNumber )
       AND
       ( project_phase_expensegroups.projectphase_expense_total >0 )
```

The parameter is for `selectionlist` that is used to choose a project to the report.

**How to have also records that have** 
`( project_phase_expensegroups.projectphase_expense_total )` with value `0` but there might be invoices for that project phase?

Tried already to add another condition like this:

```
WHERE        ( projects.project_number = @iProjectNumber )
             AND
             ( project_phase_expensegroups.projectphase_expense_total > 0 )
             OR
             ( invoicerows.invoicerow_total > 0 )
```

but while it gives **some** results - also the one with `projectphase_expense_total` with value `0`, but the report is total mess.

So my question is: what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a core problem with your query in that you are left joining to two tables, implying that rows may not exist, but then putting conditions on those tables, which will eliminate NULLs. That means your query is internally inconsistent as is.

The next problem is that you're joining two tables to `project_phases` that both may have multiple rows. Since these data are not related to each other (as proven by the fact that you have no join condition between `project_phase_expensegroups` and `invoicerows`, your query is not going to work correctly. For example, given a list of people, a list of those people's favorite foods, and a list of their favorite colors like so:

```
People

Person
------
Joe
Mary

FavoriteFoods

Person Food
------ ---------
Joe    Broccoli
Joe    Bananas
Mary   Chocolate
Mary   Cake

FavoriteColors

Person Color
------ ----------
Joe    Red
Joe    Blue
Mary   Periwinkle
Mary   Fuchsia
```

When you join these with links between Person <-> Food and Person <-> Color, you'll get a result like this:

```
Person Food      Color
------ --------- ----------
Joe    Broccoli  Red
Joe    Bananas   Red
Joe    Broccoli  Blue
Joe    Bananas   Blue
Mary   Chocolate Periwinkle
Mary   Chocolate Fuchsia
Mary   Cake      Periwinkle
Mary   Cake      Fuchsia
```

This is essentially a cross-join, also known as a Cartesian product, between the Foods and the Colors, because they have a many-to-one relationship with each person, but no relationship with each other.

There are a few ways to deal with this in the report.

1. Create ExpenseGroup and InvoiceRow subreports, that are called from the main report by a combination of `project_id` and `project_phase_id` parameters.
2. Summarize one or the other set of data into a single value. For example, you could sum the invoice rows. Or, you could concatenate the expense groups into a single string separated by commas.

Some notes:

- Please, please format your query before posting it in a question. It is almost impossible to read when not formatted. It seems pretty clear that you're using a GUI to create the query, but do us the favor of not having to format it ourselves just to help you
- While formatting, please use aliases, Don't use full table names. It just makes the query that much harder to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and tips on how to use this forum. This was my first post, so I'm learning. Thanks for your patient.

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra parentheses in your where clause in order to get the logic right.

```
WHERE ( projects.project_number = @iProjectNumber )
      AND (
           (project_phase_expensegroups.projectphase_expense_total > 0)
           OR
           (invoicerows.invoicerow_total > 0)
      )
```

Also, you're using a column in your `WHERE` clause from a table that is left joined without checking for `NULL`s. That basically makes it a (slow) inner join. If you want to include rows that don't match from that table you also need to check for `NULL`. Any other comparison besides `IS NULL` will always be false for `NULL` values. See this page for more information about SQL's three value predicate logic: http://www.firstsql.com/idefend3.htm

To keep your `LEFT JOIN`s working as you intended you would need to do this:

```
WHERE ( projects.project_number = @iProjectNumber )
      AND (
           project_phase_expensegroups.projectphase_expense_total > 0
           OR project_phase_expensegroups.project_phase_id IS NULL
           OR invoicerows.invoicerow_total > 0
           OR invoicerows.project_phase_id IS NULL
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it was kind easy after all. I changed the only the second `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` and left away condition where the query got only results over zero. Also I used `SELECT DISTINCT`

Now my report is working perfectly.